# Django: In Vue.js using axios post request 403 "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I'm new to web development and am currently stucked at a problem I can't solve easily. I'm using **Django3.2.6, django restframework (DRF) 3.14, vue3.0 and axios** (to make API calls). I wrote an APIView to lock a model while editing an it's instance:

```
class LockCmAPI(APIView):
    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(CM, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        obj.lock()
        print('locking object')
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

For the frontend I created a Vue app that **calls periodically** my **LockCmAPI** to lock the instance and prevent others from editing it:

```
let vue = Vue.createApp({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], 
    
    data: function(){
        return{
            current_cm: cm_obj, 
            intervall: null,
        }
    }, 

    methods: {
        lockCmHeartbeat(){
            console.log('locking');
            console.log(`${BACKEND_PATH+LOCK_PATH+this.current_cm.id}/`);
            axios.post(`${BACKEND_PATH+LOCK_PATH+this.current_cm.id}/`, this.current_cm, {
                xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('lock');
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
    },

    mounted() {
        this.lockCmHeartbeat();
        this.intervall = setInterval(function(){
            this.lockCmHeartbeat();
        }.bind(this), FIVE_SEC_IN_MILISEC);
    },

    beforeDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
});
vue.mount('#cm_vue_block');
```

After **running my code** I get a **403 response** with the message `"Request failed with status code 403"`. When I looked further into the response I got this `"{\"detail\":\"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.\"}"` in my **responseText**.

My Question:

- Why does it tell me I sent an **incorrect csrftoken** since it's the same csrftoken in the **cookie named csrftoken**?
- Can someone clarify it for me?
- How can I fix this problem?

THX :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who is going to have the same problem. Since the csrftoken I provided is exactly the same as the csrftoken I saw in my cookie named **csrftoken**. It had to be another issue...After reading the django documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-CSRF_HEADER_NAME :

> Default: 'HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN' The name of the request header used for
> CSRF authentication.
>
> As with other HTTP headers in request.META, the header name received
> from the server is normalized by converting all characters to
> uppercase, replacing any hyphens with underscores, and adding an
> 'HTTP_' prefix to the name. For example, if your client sends a
> 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' header, the setting should be 'HTTP_X_XSRF_TOKEN'.

I realized my csrf headername is named different to djangos default **CSRF_HEADERNAME**. In order to solve this problem I configured **xsrfHeadername** in my axios request, which looks like this:

```
axios.post(`${BACKEND_PATH + LOCK_PATH + this.current_cm.id}/`, this.current_cm, {
                xsrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
                xsrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFTOKEN',
            })
```